# MySQL Many to Many Table Join Slow Performance

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, mariadb

I have two tables with a joining column having a *Many to Many* relationship. There are a few hundred thousand records in each table. I'm seeing some very slow query performance and am having trouble singling out the issue.

Table_A:

```
+---------------------------+-------------+---------------+
| ID | Name varchar (30)    | Age int(3)  | Status int(1) |
+----+----------------------+-------------+---------------+
| 1  | Tom                  | 23          | 1             |
| 2  | Jerry                | 34          | 2             |
| 3  | Smith                | 21          | 1             |
| 4  | Ben                  | 46          | 5             |
+---------------------------+-------------+---------------+
```

Table_B:

```
+---------------------------+-------------+---------------+
| ID | Name varchar (30)    | Sign int(3) | Status int(1) |
+----+----------------------+-------------+---------------+
| 1  | Tom                  | 12          | 1             |
| 2  | Smith                | 8           | 1             |
| 3  | Tom                  | 3           | 0             |
| 4  | Tom                  | 10          | 1             |
+---------------------------+-------------+---------------+
```

I need to get the Age of each Name in Table A who has at least one row in Table B with a match on Name and a Status (Table B) of 1.

I tried:

```
SELECT Age FROM Table_A
LEFT JOIN Table_B ON Table_A.Name=Table_B.Name
WHERE Table_B.Status=1;
```

That query takes so long I haven't waited for it to return.
I then tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Age FROM Table_A
LEFT JOIN Table_B ON Table_A.Name=Table_B.Name AND Table_B.Status=1;
```

That returned very fast.
I tested further and tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Age FROM Table_A
LEFT JOIN Table_B ON Table_A.Name=Table_B.Name
WHERE Table_B.Status=1;
```

That again didn't return.

I'm confused as to what's going on here.

In the last query shouldn't the WHERE condition act the same as the previous query's JOIN ON condition (Status=1)?

Why does SELECT DISTINCT return results whereas without using DISTINCT the process takes forever?

Comment: First of all, you probably want to use inner join instead of the left outer.

Comment: Both have given me the same result.

Comment: There are three questions i would ask here. (1) Why do you even join by name? (2) What are your primary keys and what are your foreign keys? And last this is not many, where is your third table?

Comment: The `select` queries can be useful, but we really need the result of the `explain` queries to see what's going on. My prime candidate is a lack of (proper) indexes.

Answer (score 1):

For a many-to-many table, do not include an `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  Do have the `PRIMARY KEY` include both other ids.  Do have another index.  Do use InnoDB.

See [*More details, plus rationale*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing an explain plan (or whatever the MySQL equivalent is) it's impossible to say for certain.

My guess would be that the server knows that your `OUTER JOIN' to table B is completely irrelevant when you use`SELECT DISTINCT`, so it just runs against table A and gets the Age values from there without even performing the`JOIN`. Do you see why the`OUTER JOIN` is irrelevant?

In the first query the server needs to perform the `JOIN` to get the right number of rows back.

When you add the additional logic to your `WHERE` clause in the last query you've effectively turned it into an `INNER JOIN`, so now the `JOIN` has to happen again and it takes a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have indexes set on the Table_A.Name, Table_B.Name and Table_B.Status columns

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need a `LEFT JOIN`, because you only care about matches:

```
SELECT a.Age
FROM Table_A a JOIN 
     Table_B b
     ON Table_A.Name = b.Name
WHERE b.Status = 1;
```

For this query can take advantage of indexes on `Table_B(status, name)` and `Table_A(Name, Age)`.